# Compositing millions of images on a canvas

Tags: image, go, draw

I'm trying to render a series of isometric blocks on a blank canvas. This however is taking up an enormous number of resources and execution time. Is there any way to efficiently render albeit similiar images to canvas?

Here's the code (For representative purposes):

```
var iso = image.NewRGBA(image.Rectangle{Min: image.Point{X: 0, Y: 0}, Max: image.Point{X: 32 * 16, Y: 383*17+274}})

t,err := os.Open("stone.png") // Is a 16x16 png
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
}

texture, _  := png.Decode(t)

x, y, z := 0,0,0
for i:=0; i<=16*16*16; i++ {
    if x == 16 {
        x=0
        z+=1
    }

    if z == 16 {
        z=0
        y+=1
    }

    draw.Draw(iso, texture.Bounds().Add(image.Point{Y: iso.Bounds().Dy() - 152 - x*8 + z*8 - y*17, X: z*16 + x*16}), texture, image.Point{X: 0, Y: 0}, draw.Over)


    x+=1
   
}

f, _ := os.Create("output.png")
png.Encode(f,iso)
```

- [CPU Profile Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4bnS.png)
- [Memory Profile Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pKAZ.png)

Thanks!

Comment: You are writing a png file for each iteration.

Comment: You would save a fair bit of code by using one for loop for each x, y, z rather than a single loop and then maintaining x, y, z by hand.

Comment: @PaulHankin

1. Yes, I am writing a png file to bigger image.RGBA. That's what I want to achieve, albeit there are multiple textures that I draw on `iso`.

2. I thought nesting would be more expensive than a simple loop, but I will check it out!

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. You are creating a file `output.png` and encoding a png to it on every iteration.

Comment: @PaulHankin Sorry for that! I was actually replicating my code without the other complexities. The actual code doesn't do that!

Comment: if the actual code does not do "that", how is that relevant at solving your issue ?

Comment: @mh-cbon I was talking about the file being created and being written to at every iteration, which I then edited to be outside the loop as intended.  The main bottleneck seems to be the draw.Draw function call though, as seen in the CPU profile.